# Where can I find free asp.net master pages?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Does anyone know a website that provides free goodlooking asp.net master pages
that i can use in my website?

Comment: There are sites that provide free website templates, many of which look pretty good.  Wouldn't that suffice?  Why does it need to be in the form of an ASP .NET Master Page?

Comment: So that the designer of the Template would design the modules of the template and partition the template well

Comment: Most good templates have areas for content specified in them.  You can put the layout parts in the master page and subsequent pages to accommodate your site design.  Honestly, if you limit yourself to only template providers who produce ASP .NET code for you, that will _drastically_ limit your options.  (I know of none.)  But if you just want a website template, there are plenty available.

Comment: Keep in mind that breaking up a master page from subsequent pages isn't a one-size-fits-all operation.  Do you really want a graphic designer who knows/cares nothing of your project dictating how you organize your code?

Answer (score 2):

While it may be easiest to just drop in a MasterPage, I haven't seen anywhere where you can do that. Try other template sites like [Open Web Design](http://openwebdesign.org/) and then apply them yo your own MasterPage.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I found the other day. It will not produce Master Pages as you have asked for, but is a tool for producing quick and basic designs which you can then get the HTML for.

http://www.artisteer.com/

It is then easy just to take the HTML and stick it into your Master Page.